# Many to many relationship on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, many-to-many, graph-theory, graph-databases

Am newer in Neo4j and have some difficults to represent complex relationships (many to many relations), please see the two linked images below (Class diagram and its relationnal schema).

[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6Zf.png).

[relationnal schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGqIH.png)

As I've shown from the images, I would like to represent on Neo4j the green relationship (Consultation one).

Could you help me please !!!

Comment: No idea why you would use a graph database to model that kind of data. You'd be far better off with just a standard RDBMS.

Comment: am working on a project and i would like to modeling this system on Neo4j.. Do you think we couldn't reprsent it with graphs?

Comment: It can be done, but the type of data you have is far better suited for a relational model than a graph model. You can drive in a screw with a hammer, but that doesn't mean it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: // **___[v2] : Création d'une consultation**

`MATCH 
(dp:DossierPatient{numDos:1}), 
(dr:Docteur{matricule:1}), 
(ord:Ordonnance{numOrd:1})

MERGE (cons:Consultation{numDos:dp.numDos, codeDocteur:dr.matricule, dateC:'13/11/2022'})
ON CREATE SET cons.diagnostic='présence de fièvre, vomissement'

MERGE (dp)<-[:concerne]-(cons)-[:concerne]->(ord)
MERGE (cons) -[:effectuée_par]->(dr);`

Comment: // **version 3** pour la relation docteur et dossier patients, on va modifier dossierpatient en ajoutant un tableau des medcin qui a consulter puis on va faire la relation

`MATCH (dp1:DossierPatient{numDos:1})
SET dp1.a_consulter = [1,2];
MATCH (dp:DossierPatient), (d:Docteur)
WHERE d.matricule IN dp.a_consulter
MERGE (dp)-[:CONSULTATION{dateC:"02/02/2020",diagnostic:"diagnostic1"}]->(d);`

Comment: // **___[version 1] : Création d'une consultation en trois étapes** 
//etape 1 : on recherche les noeuds liés 

`MATCH (dp:DossierPatient{numDos:1}), (dr:Docteur{matricule:1}), (ord:Ordonnance{numOrd:1}) //etape 2 : join table CREATE (cons:Consultation{dateC:'13/11/2022', diagnostic:'Manque de sommeil, perte d\'apétit, fatigue'}), //relationship (dp)<-[:concerne]-(cons)-[:concerne]->(ord), (cons) -[:effectuée_par]->(dr); `

Comment: This three last comment how I tried to do..
am not sure if it's good or not

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you see please ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen "No idea why you would use a graph database to model that kind of data..."
That's a bold statement - can you back it up?

Comment: @Marj No idea how to "back up" a statement where I say I have no idea. I can double down though: I have *really* no idea. Given the nature of the data model, if you have insights about what probable use cases would be better addressed with a graph database than a relational database, I'll be happy to learn about them.